# Inline onclick handler does not work

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use INLINE callback function so, I have the following html markup:

```
    var callback = function (index) {
        return function () {
            return action.delete({
                index: index
            })
        }
    }
    var markup = items.map(function (item, index) {
        return ('<button onclick="return ' + callback(index) + ';">Delete</button>')
    }).join('\n') 

    document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = markup
```

But when I click on the button, my callback does not work. What's wrong with the code above? Thanks.

Comment: *"What's wrong with the code above?"* you are trying to concatenate a **function** with a **string**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `callback(index)` returns function, but when it is concatenate with strings `.toString()` method of function implicitly invoked and returns body of function as a string.

You code should be look like this:

```
var callback = function (index) {
     return action.delete({
        index: index
     });
}
var markup = items.map(function (item, index) {
    return ('<button onclick="return callback(' + index + ');">Delete</button>')
}).join('\n') 

document.getElementById('#main').innerHTML = markup
```

And `callback` function must be define in global scope in that case.

it is better to use `addEventListener` to set listener function for click event.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is there a chance to use callback from non-global scope?

Comment: use `addEventListener`. It is much better aproach.